# @Html.ActionLink ignoring route values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("English", "ChangeCulture", "CreditCard", new { culture = "en-US" }, null)
```

And in my controller `SomeController`, there's this:

```
public ActionResult ChangeCulture(string culture)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    // ...
}
```

When I run this, I get an error inside `AnAction()`, pointing to `someParam` and saying that it's null. I'm pretty sure I'm using the right overload for `@Html.ActionLink`, having even tried using named parameters, but it still says it's null. What am I missing?

I have tried renaming `culture` to just `c`.

Comment: What does the rendered link look like?

Comment: From what I can see, it should be working. What URL is produced by that `ActionLink` and, if relevant, what does your route look like?

Comment: @AntP @TimS. `<a href="/00246C4D6C70/SomeController/AnAction?someParam=asd">LinkName</a>` Where `00246C4D6C70` is just some MAC address.

Comment: The MVC Engine resolves controller name without the Controller affix. Make sure you passing only Some not SomeController!

Comment: @Fals makes a good point - also, you should use your *actual* parameter names, *actual* property names and *actual* action/controller names - they affect binding so changing them can mask your problem.

Comment: @Fals Yup, I am just passing in `Some` indeed!

Comment: @AntP I've changed it now to use the real names. Thanks for the reminder, I always forget that those could be a problem too.

Comment: @idlackage I tried your code here and and works perfecly. Theres something else wrong.

Comment: Yep, I can't reproduce this either. Are you sure the parameter is null? Have you inserted a breakpoint in the first line of the action and debugged?

Comment: @AntP Ahh, I see something strange now. The argument gets passed in fine, but then the page refreshes (with `RedirectToAction`), and the action is somehow called again--apparently because the I've been redirecting to `ChangeCulture` without knowing it (was using a Viewbag variable). This makes sense and works now when I change the redirect location. Thanks!